# Find the Count of common elements within the two nested Lists

Tags: java, list, comparison, nested-lists

Compare each element present in list of String lists object1 with another object object2 in Java

I have a list of String lists initialized to object1 as mentioned below:

```
List<List<String>> object1 = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"),
                                       Arrays.asList("D", "E", "F"), 
                                       Arrays.asList("G", "H", "I"));
```

I have a another list of String lists initialized to object2 as mentioned below:

```
List<List<String>> object2 = Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"),
                                       Arrays.asList("D", "E", "F"), 
                                       Arrays.asList("G", "H", "J"));
```

How do I compare each element between two objects one by one in same order

Need to initialize a counter variable to track number of common elements present between two objects.

Expected result : `8`

Comment: And what is your required result/output? Do you just want a boolean value if both objects contain same elements in same order? Because in that case just using the equals method should be enough. PS: Your objects are bot named "object1"

Comment: I need the count of common elements present between two objects too using count variable

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question - Its two different objects

Comment: So the result for your example should be `2` because the first 2 Lists are equal, or should it be `6` because the first 2 equal lists contain 6 elements?

Comment: The count should be 8 (only last element is different)

Comment: @impstuffsforcse It is worth to provide this information in the question. Can you please [*add*](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73193487/edit) the explanation regarding expected output. Even after reading the comments, it's **not** completely clear if the order matter, what if one list contains more nested lists than the other, how to deal with duplicates (if any) ?

Comment: So the order is not important? What if we have `[["a","b"]["c","a"]]` and `[["a","a"]["b","e"]]`, what would be the result? `3` - `a`+`a`+`b`?

Comment: What do you mean by saying in the `same order`? Does it imply that two list are guaranteed to have the same size and all the lists nested within them as well? How the following input should be treated `[["a","a","a"]]` and `[["a","b"]["a"]]` or such case is not possible? Please clarify the constraints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate a `Map` representing the number of occurrences of each element in a list for both *lists*.

And then add up the *values* associated with *keys* that are present in both maps of frequencies by choosing the *smallest value* in every pair of *values*.

If you're comfortable with streams, this logic can be implementing like that:

```
public static Map<String, Long> getFrequencies(List<List<String>> list) {
    
    return list.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Function.identity(),
            Collectors.counting()
        ));
}

public static long countCommonValues(Map<String, Long> map1, Map<String, Long> map2) {
    
    return map1.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> map2.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
        .mapToLong(entry -> Math.min(entry.getValue(), map2.get(entry.getKey())))
        .sum();
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> list1 = List.of(
        List.of("A", "B", "A"),
        List.of("D", "E", "H"),
        List.of("G", "H", "I"));
    
    List<List<String>> list2 = List.of(
        List.of("A", "B", "C", "D"),
        List.of("D", "E", "F", "A"),
        List.of("G", "H", "J", "H"));

    System.out.println(countCommonValues(getFrequencies(list1), getFrequencies(list2)));
}
```

*Output:*

```
8   // "A", "A", "B", "D", "E", "G", "H", "H"
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/tFD)

---

In case if order is important and nested lists are not guaranteed to be of the same size, we can flatten both lists and then compare elements at corresponding indices.

```
public static <T> long countCommonValues(List<List<T>> list1, List<List<T>> list2) {
    
    List<T> flattened1 = flatten(list1);
    List<T> flattened2 = flatten(list2);
    
    return IntStream.range(0, Math.min(flattened1.size(), flattened2.size()))
        .filter(i -> flattened1.get(i).equals(flattened2.get(i)))
        .count();
}

public static <T> List<T> flatten(List<List<T>> list) {
    return list.stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .toList();
}
```

Comment: can we use count() right after filter() since filter gets all the common keys in both maps?

Comment: @yulinxp Did you try it? You can, but the result would be incorrect, this stream doesn't counts entries.

Comment: Yes I tried that. It seems to be working for me.

Comment: @yulinxp I've forgotten that I've used the test case provided by OP. Where all values are unique, but it might not be the case. The map is needed for cases when there are several identical elements, `sum()` adds up **values**, i.e. the number of occurrences. Did you get the idea?

Comment: @yulinxp `count()` will fail if there would be duplicated elements.

Comment: Original post doesn't say much about duplicates. My understand is that even if any list has more than one "A", we still get one count for "A".

Comment: @yulinxp `even if any list has more than one "A", we still get one count for "A"` - that's a pure **assumption**, and code should never be written based on assumptions. Original problem statement is: *"number of common elements"*. It says elements, but doesn't say *distinct* elements.

Comment: @yulinxp I've also [*requested a on this point clarification*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73193487/compare-each-element-present-in-list-of-string-lists-object1-with-another-object/73197173?noredirect=1#comment129273856_73193487), but OP hasn't responded yet.

Answer (score 2):

To get your required output the simplest way is to use 2 nested loops to iterate over both Lists and Sublists and check each element for equality, using a simple counter variable to keep track of equal elements:

```
int equalElements = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < object1.size() && i < object2.size(); i++) {
    final List<String> subList1 = object1.get(i);
    final List<String> subList2 = object2.get(i);
    for(int x = 0; x < subList1.size() && x < subList2.size(); x++) {
        if (Objects.equals(subList1.get(x), subList2.get(x))) {
            equalElements++;
        }
    }
}
    
System.out.println(equalElements);
```

Comment: What is "Objects" present in if condition?

Comment: [java.util.Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) - A helper class introduces in Java 7 with many static helper methods. You could also do `subList1.get(x).equals(subList2.get(x));` but that would throw a `NullPointerException` in case `subList1.get(x)` returned `null`. The static `Objects.equals` method can handle those null cases as well without throwing an Exception. In short `Objects.equals(subList1.get(x), subList2.get(x))` is just a null safe way of doing `subList1.get(x).equals(subList2.get(x));`